# Special runtime representation of [] type?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the simple definition of a length-indexed vector:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat 

infixr 5 :> 
data Vec (n :: Nat) a where 
  V0 :: Vec 'Z a 
  (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a
```

Naturally I would at some point need the following function:

```
vec2list :: Vec n a -> [a]
```

However, this function is really just a fancy identity. I believe that the runtime representations of these two types are the same, so

```
vec2list :: Vec n a -> [a]  
vec2list = unsafeCoerce
```

should work. Alas, it does not:

```
>vec2list ('a' :> 'b' :> 'c' :> V0)
""
```

Every input simply returns the empty list. So I assume my understand is lacking. To test it, I define the following:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show) 

vec2list' :: Vec n a -> List a 
vec2list' = unsafeCoerce 

test1 = vec2list' ('a' :> 'b' :> 'c' :> V0)

data SomeVec a = forall n . SomeVec (Vec n a) 

list'2vec :: List a -> SomeVec a 
list'2vec x = SomeVec (unsafeCoerce x)
```

Surprisingly this works! It certainly isn't an issue with the GADT then (my initial thought).

I think that the `List` type is really identical at runtime to `[]`. I try to test this too:

```
list2list :: [a] -> List a 
list2list = unsafeCoerce 

test2 = list2list "abc"
```

and it works! Based on this fact, I have to conclude that `[a]` and `List a` must have the same runtime representation. And yet, the following

```
list2list' :: List a -> [a] 
list2list' = unsafeCoerce 

test3 = list2list' (Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' (Cons 'c' Nil)))
```

does not work. `list2list'` again always returns the empty list. I believe that "having identical runtime representations" must be a symmetric relation, so this doesn't seem to make sense.

I began to think maybe there's something funny with "primitive" types - but I always believed that `[]` is only special syntactically, not semantically. It seems that's the case:

```
data Pair a b = Pair a b deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)  

tup2pair :: (a,b) -> Pair a b 
tup2pair = unsafeCoerce 

pair2tup :: Pair a b -> (a,b) 
pair2tup = unsafeCoerce
```

The first function works and the second does not - same as the in the case of `List` and `[]`. Although in this case, `pair2tup` segfaults as opposed to always returning the empty list.

It seems to be *consistently* asymmetric with respect to types which use "built-in" syntax. Back to the `Vec` example, the following

```
list2vec :: [a] -> SomeVec a 
list2vec x = SomeVec (unsafeCoerce x)
```

works just fine as well! The GADT really isn't special.

The question is: **how do the runtime representations of types which use "built-in" syntax differ from those that do not?**

Alternatively, how does one write a zero-cost coercion from `Vec n a` to `[a]`? This doesn't answer the question but solves the problem.

Testing was done with GHC 7.10.3.

---

As noted by a commenter, this behaviour is only present when interpreting. When compiled, all functions work as expected. The question still applies, just to *runtime representation when interpreting*.

Comment: "Works fine" in combination with `unsafeCoerce` is like pointing to a ruin and saying "look, it still stands". It's like using a `reinterpret_cast<T*>(…)` in C++. With the correct reason, it will work, but on the other hand GHC does not infer any `Coercible` instance for any of your types. That being said, IIRC `RuntimeRep` changes in GHC 8 (see `GHC.Types`)  due to [levity polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35318562/1139697).

Comment: To answer your second question: `newtype Vec (n :: Nat) a = MkVec [a]` together with `v0 :: Vec 'Z a; v0 = []`, `(|>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a; (|>) x = coerce . (x:) . coerce`, where `coerce` is from `Data.Coerce`. The compiler then correctly infers that `n :: Nat` is just a phantom type.

Comment: @Zeta Like you said, with the correct reasoning it should work. I don't think this is explicitly one of the "approved" uses, but in practice the runtime representations of "morally equal" types are *usually* the same, except apparently in the cases above. This question isn't about high level design of Haskell code. It is about the guts of GHC. The alternative question is really sort of a trick - I'm pretty sure it's impossible without `unsafeCoerce` - but I don't want to discourage someone from trying to prove me wrong.

Comment: This is a neat observation! By the way, you can `unsafeCoerce` to `Int` to look at the underlying bits, not that they necessarily tell you that much on their own...

Comment: Fyi, all examples that you posted work fine for me when compiled with GHC 7.10.1, but fail for me in GHCI, so the problem is not the run-time representation in general, but inside GHCI.

Comment: and that answers my suspicion -- I think the magic here is compiled types and pointer tagging...

Comment: @user2407038: Fair enough. That being said, I'm wondering why `n :: Nat`'s role has to be nominal and not phantom. Hm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now to answer your main question, [this thread appears to have the answer](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.glasgow.user/22222): start ghci with `-fobject-code`:

```
$ ghci /tmp/vec.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/vec.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> print $ vec2list ('a' :> 'b' :> 'c' :> V0)
""
```

With `-fobject-code`:

```
$ ghci -fobject-code /tmp/vec.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/vec.hs, /tmp/vec.o )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
Prelude Main> print $ vec2list ('a' :> 'b' :> 'c' :> V0)
"abc"
```

The modules that contain `[]` and `(,)` are all compiled, which causes their runtime representation to be different from isomorphic datatypes in interpreted modules. According to Simon Marlow on the thread I linked, interpreted modules add annotations for the debugger. I think this also explains why `tup2pair` works and `pair2tup` doesn't: missing annotations isn't a problem for interpreted modules, but the compiled modules choke on the extra annotations.

`-fobject-code` has some downsides: longer compilation time, only brings exported functions in scope, but it has the additional advantage that running the code is much faster.

Comment: I was overthinking this so hard.. of course it couldn't be due to special syntax. That would be crazy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To answer only your alternative question, you could create a `newtype` with a non-exported constructor to give a list a type-level length and a zero-cost coercion to lists:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

module Vec (Nat(..), Vec, v0, (>:>), vec2list) where

data Nat = Z | S Nat

newtype Vec (n :: Nat) a = Vec { unVec :: [a] }

v0 :: Vec Z a
v0 = Vec []

infixr 5 >:>
(>:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a
a >:> (Vec as) = Vec (a : as)

vec2list :: Vec n a -> [a]
vec2list (Vec as) = as
```

As long as the `Vec` constructor is not in scope (so only `v0` and `>:>` can be used to construct vectors) the invariant that the type-level number represents the length can't be violated.

(This approach definitely has my preference over `unsafeCoerce`, as anything with `unsafeCoerce` could break with every update of GHC or on different platforms.)

Comment: I kind of see this as a non-answer - to me changing the type is changing the problem. Yes, I am aware of newtypes. In practice, I'm pretty much married to my representation of Vec - performance is really a side concern for me (at least where I use Vec). I know it is even possible to simulate dependant-style pattern matching for the newtype `Vec` with pattern synonyms (because I have done so), but until pattern syns get exhaustiveness checking, that is a non-solution as well.