# Is it possible to establish Coercible instances between custom types and standard library ones?

Tags: haskell, deriving, coerce, derivingvia

For a simple example, say I want a type to represent tic-tac-toe marks:

```hs
data Mark = Nought | Cross
```

Which is the same as `Bool`

```hs
Prelude> :info Bool
data Bool = False | True    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
```

But there's no `Coercible Bool Mark` between them, not even if I import `GHC.Types` (I first thought maybe GHC needs `Bool`'s defining place to be visible), the only way to have this instance seems to be through `newtype`.

Probably I could have defined `newtype Mark = Mark Bool` and define `Nought` and `Cross` with bidirectional patterns, I wish there's something simpler than that.

Comment: There's `unsafeCoerce`, which will probably work but which would not be recommended. The only way to get a `Coercible` instance would be local, using `unsafeCoerce`. `case unsafeCoerce (Coercion @() @()) :: Coercible Mark Bool of Coercion -> ....`. I wouldn't really suggest it unless there's a desperate performance need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck.  As the [documentation for `Data.Coerce` explains](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#t:Coercible), "one can pretend that the following three kinds of instances exist:"

- Self-instances, as in `instance Coercible a a`,
- Instances for coercing between two versions of a data type that differ by representational or phantom type parameters, as in `instance Coercible a a' => Coercible (Maybe a) (Maybe a')`, and
- Instances between new types.

Furthermore, "Trying to manually declare an instance of `Coercible` is an error", so that's all you get.  There are no instances between arbitrarily different data types, even if they look similar.

---

This may seem frustratingly limiting, but consider this: if there were a `Coercible` instance between `Bool` and `Mark`, what's stopping it from coercing `Nought` to `True` and `Cross` to `False`?  It may be that `Bool` and `Mark` are represented in memory the same way, but there is no guarantee that they are semantically similar enough to warrant a `Coercible` instance.

---

Your solution of using a newtype and pattern synonyms is a great, safe way to get around the problem, even if it is a little annoying.

Another option is to consider using `Generic`.  For instance, check out the idea of `genericCoerce` from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66011340/ensuring-that-two-gadts-have-the-same-underlying-representation-in-ghc-haske/66021612#66021612)

Answer (score 8):

`Coercible Bool Mark` is not required. `Mark`-instances can be derived via `Bool` without it.

[`Generic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generic) types whose generic representations ([`Rep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Rep)) are [`Coercible`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#t:Coercible) can be converted to each other:

```
   from           coerce              to
A -----> Rep A () -----> Rep Via () -----> Via
```

For the datatype `Mark` this means instances (`Eq`, ..) can be derived via instances of `Bool`.

```
type Mark :: Type
data Mark = Nought | Cross
 deriving
 stock Generic

 deriving Eq
 via Bool <-> Mark
```

How does `Bool <-> Mark` work?

```
type    (<->) :: Type -> Type -> Type
newtype via <-> a = Via a
```

First we capture the constraint that we can `coerce` between the generic representation of two types:

```
type CoercibleRep :: Type -> Type -> Constraint
type CoercibleRep via a = (Generic via, Generic a, Rep a () `Coercible` Rep via ())
```

Given this constraint we can move from `a` to it `via` type, creating intermediate `Rep`s:

```
translateTo :: forall b a. CoercibleRep a b => a -> b
translateTo = from @a @() >>> coerce >>> to @b @()
```

Now we can easily write an `Eq` instance for this type, we assume an `Eq via` instance for the via type (`Bool` in our case)

```
instance (CoercibleRep via a, Eq via) => Eq (via <-> a) where
 (==) :: (via <-> a) -> (via <-> a) -> Bool
 Via a1 == Via a2 = translateTo @via a1 == translateTo @via a2
```

The instance for `Semigroup` requires translating `via` back to `a`

```
instance (CoercibleRep via a, Semigroup via) => Semigroup (via <-> a) where
 (<>) :: (via <-> a) -> (via <-> a) -> (via <-> a)
 Via a1 <> Via a2 = Via do
  translateTo @a do
     translateTo @via a1 <> translateTo @via a2
```

Now we can derive `Eq` and `Semigroup`!

```
-- >> V3 "a" "b" "c" <> V3 "!" "!" "!"
-- V3 "a!" "b!" "c!"
type V4 :: Type -> Type
data V4 a = V4 a a a a
 deriving
 stock Generic

 deriving (Eq, Semigroup)
 via (a, a, a, a) <-> V4 a
```

Using a `newtype` from the beginning avoids this boilerplate but once it's up it can be reused. It is simple to write a newtype and use pattern synonyms to cover it up.

Comment: I don't see a definition of `<->` anywhere. Could you include that?

Comment: `GenericIso` is a mystery too. Is this answer missing some imports?

Comment: I fixed the missing definitions, I had renamed it to `CoercibleRep` halfway through

Answer (score 7):

This isn’t possible yet, and pattern synonyms are a good solution for now. I often use code like this to derive useful instances for a type that happens to be isomorphic to an existing primitive type.

```
module Mark
  ( Mark(Nought, Cross)
  ) where

newtype Mark = Mark Bool
  deriving stock (…)
  deriving newtype (…)
  deriving (…) via Any
  …

pattern Nought = Mark False
pattern Cross = Mark True
```

Coercion between unrelated ADTs is also not on the [list of permitted unsafe coercions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:unsafeCoerce-35-). Last I knew, in practice in GHC, coercions between `Mark` and `Bool` will work only if the values in question are fully evaluated, because they have a small number of constructors, so the constructor index is stored in the tag bits of the pointer at runtime. But an arbitrary thunk of type `Mark` or `Bool` can’t be coerced reliably, and the method doesn’t generalise to types with more than {4, 8} constructors (on resp. {32, 64}-bit systems).

Moreover, the code generator and runtime representation of objects both change periodically, so even if this works now (I don’t know), it will probably break in the future anyway.

My hope is that we get a generalised `Coercible` in the future that can accommodate more coercions than just `newtype`-of-`T` ↔ `T`, or even better, that allows us to specify a stable ABI for a data type. To my knowledge, no one is actively working on that in Haskell, although there is some similar work going on in Rust for [safe transmute](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2981), so maybe someone will smuggle it back over to functional-land.

(Speaking of ABI, you *could* use the FFI for this, and I’ve done so in circumstances where I was already writing foreign code and knew the `Storable` instances matched. [`alloca`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:alloca) a suitably sized buffer, [`poke`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#v:poke) a value of type `Bool` into it, [`castPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html#v:castPtr) the `Ptr Bool` into a `Ptr Mark`, [`peek`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#v:peek) the `Mark` out of it, and [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) the whole shebang.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `unsafeCoerce` will be fine, though never officially supported. Whether a value is evaluated/tagged or not shouldn't be relevant. In older (basically, non-bleeding-edge) GHC versions, the bigger danger was that the simplifier could float coercions around in bad ways, basically taking a use of `unsafeCoerce @Mark @Bool` and letting the coercion axiom `Mark ~ Bool` float somewhere invalid, like maybe tripping specialization rules. I think that's fixed now.

Comment: One situation where you have to be extra careful with `unsafeCoerce` is when different types are compiled with different options affecting unpacking. `data Foo = Foo {-# UNPACK #-} !Bar` will only unpack `Bar` with optimizations enabled, and of course `-XStrict`, `-funbox-strict-fields` and `-fno-unbox-small-strict-fields` will have their effects.

Comment: This `Storable` plan is bizarre. In what circumstances is that better than writing a pure Haskell translation function with no `unsafe` features at all? (Side benefit of staying pure: the behavior is transparent enough that the compiler can remind you that the translation needs to be updated when one or the other type's definition changes.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: lol it’s meant to read as bizarre, it’s not better. In my case I had an array of data marshalled to C++, mutated, returned, and decoded to a different type to record that the transformation had happened in the foreign land. In terms of both correctness and performance, it’s not worthwhile for a single value.