# Equivalence between '.' and '$'

Tags: haskell, types, syntax

I have an expression:

```
gcastWith p1 $
gcastWith p2 $
e
```

That works ok. Now I am trying to rewrite it as:

```
((gcastWith p1) .
 (gcastWith p2)) $
e
```

And it doesn't work (doesn't typecheck). However this works:

```
((gcastWith p1) .
 (gcastWith p2)) -- note I removed the dollar
e
```

Am I missing something obvious about how `$` and `.` operate?

Comment: Nothing about `$` and `.` themselves, more about the weirdness in `gcastWith :: (a :~: b) -> ((a ~ b) => r) -> r` with a constraint in the middle of the type signature.

Comment: Well yes, but it's legal Haskell, and I was expecting the above transformation to be correct for all legal constructs. Obviously I was wrong.

Comment: `$` and `.` can behave very weirdly once you start using extensions. `$`, for example, has a [long history of surprising people](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39193282/3072788).

Comment: By the way, do you have a minimal, complete, verifiable example for this? I suspect you are hitting impredicative types, but I can't off the top of my head find something which fails in the way you describe...

Comment: A lot of code transformations that should be correct for all legal Haskell can fail when you're using type system extensions. A number of them sacrifice the "all types can be inferred" property of vanilla Haskell. Code transformations that "morally" give the same result can produce different intermediate expressions; if those are ones that cause problems for type inference, then you can get type errors from one form but not another even when they should result in the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it's some restrictions caused by how type inference works. In basic Hindley-Milner types like

```
f :: (forall a. G a) -> T
```

are forbidden. GHC Haskell allows them (with suitable extensions turned on), but still uses the HM restriction requiring that a type variable can never be instantiated to a polytype.

This causes some surprise: `f e` type checks but `f $ e` fails since the type variables in the type of `$` should be instantiated to a polytype.

```
e :: forall a. G a
f :: (forall a. G a) -> T
f e :: T

($) :: (b -> c) -> b -> c

Type checking ($) f e:

       b ~ (forall a. G a)   -- forbidden polytype!
       c ~ T
```

Since `f $ e` is *very* common in Haskell, and we really want things like `runST $ do ....` to work, the GHC devs have added a special-case typing rule for `$`. Essentially, when fully applied, `f $ e` is typed like `f e`.

There is no such special case in the typing system for `f . g . h $ e` at the moment. This can make it fail when `f $ g $ h $ e` works fine.

Comment: Are there solutions for this problem?

Comment: @ThreeFx Developer side, you can use one other other styles, like using parentheses, or using `$`. Compiler side, one could extend the special case to capture the idiom `f . g $ e` as well. Personally, I'm not too happy to see more and more special cases in the type system. Perhaps this is still OK.