# About the type signature of `($)`

Tags: haskell

If I ever want to reinvent `($)`, here's what I would write:

```hs
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ a = f a
```

Which is nearly identical to the [official definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%24), except the use of a sophisticated type `TYPE`:

```hs
($) :: forall r a (b :: TYPE r). (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x =  f x
```

What is `TYPE`, and what's its necessity here?

Comment: You can read more information here: https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/representation_polymorphism.html#runtime-rep

Comment: This is addressed by [*Why dollar ($) operator is so complex in GHC 8.0.1?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39186288/2751851)

Comment: I closed the question since I think it's a duplicate, as @duplode pointed out. OP, if you believe your question is more nuanced than the older one, feel free to argue so. I can reopen this if needed.