# GHC can't infer unlifted kind

Tags: haskell, types, happy, polykinds

I'm running up against what looks like invalid code generated by Happy. The problem boils down to GHC not inferring a polykinded type signature for a function. Here is an example of this:

```
{-# Language MagicHash #-}

f x = ()

main = pure (f 1#)
```

Since GHC is inferring `f :: a -> ()` where `a :: *`, this fails with

```
 • Couldn't match a lifted type with an unlifted type
   When matching the kind of ‘GHC.Prim.Int#’
 • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘1#’
   In the first argument of ‘pure’, namely ‘(f 1#)’
   In the expression: pure (f 1#)
```

Are there any language pragmas I could just turn on to get this code to compile? I know I could in theory just add type signatures but, as this is code generated by Happy which I'd prefer not to have to manually modify anything.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35320729/180286. Basically a function can't be polymorphic over kinds, unless you really want to, and only in GHC 8+

Comment: If Happy generates code which doesn't compile in this way, it is probably a bug in Happy (perhaps one which can be worked around!). Can you put together a minimal Happy example which produces such code? I don't think GHC ever infers a kind other than `*` for a polytype.

Comment: @user2407038 Although my question still stands, this particular Happy bug is easily fixed. Basically any generated code that uses `happyMonad2Reduce` and was not generated with `-a` will have this problem for the `nt :: Int#` variable (which is not used without `-a`, hence the type inference issues). I'm currently fighting some nastier Happy issues, so filing an issue for _this_ is going on the back burner. :)

Comment: @Alec Thanks for the explanation, I see you are already aware of the problem/solution higher up in the toolchain. This question is interesting in a much broader context than Happy, but unfortunately I don't think it has a solution (other than writing a type signature). Best of luck!

Comment: Inference or no, the argument to `f` can't have a polykinded (specifically, levity-polymorphic) type. `x` is a variable with the type that would be levity-polymorphic, and no variables can have such types. So you'd need GHC to infer a *monomorphic* type here. My guess is that whereas the type checker can delay class-polymorphic code to apply the monomorphism restriction, it has no mechanism for doing so with (fundamentally) levity-polymorphic code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted at by @dfeuer, this is impossible. In the worst case, GHC would have to look for usages of a given function across the whole project in order to infer the levity of an argument.

This was reported as a [bug in Happy](https://github.com/simonmar/happy/issues/95) and has since been [fixed](https://github.com/simonmar/happy/pull/97).