# Why does the $ operator in Haskell have such a strange type?

Tags: haskell, types

According to [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-36-) the `$` operator has type

```
($) :: forall r a (b :: TYPE r). (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

while I always thought it was

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

There is some explanation in the docs

> Note that `($)` is levity-polymorphic in its result type, so that foo $ True where foo :: Bool -> Int# is well-typed

but I don't understand it at all. Could somebody explain to me which issue this approach solves?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318562/what-is-levity-polymorphism