# What is the difference between the $ operator in Haskell and Purescript

Tags: haskell, purescript

[This document](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Differences-from-Haskell.md#no-special-treatment-of-), about the differences between Haskell and Purescript, says the following about the `$` operator

> GHC provides a special typing rule for the $ operator, so that the following natural application to the rank-2 runST function is well-typed:
>
> ```hs
> runST $ do
>   ...
> ```
>
> PureScript does not provide this rule, so it is necessary to either
>
> omit the operator: runST do ...
> or use parentheses instead: runST (do ...)

Which typing rule is meant by this? And how does this impact the example of `runST`?

Comment: [I'd initially assumed that it might be "Levity Polymorphism" as discussed in this question, but I'm struggling to understand how that would apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35320729/1486968)

Comment: I seem to remember that Haskell's special typing rule for `($)` is anyway being removed, but can't find the reference now.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's gotta be part of the `ImpredicativeTypes` overhaul, right?

Comment: @dfeuer right! https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/b94aec096d680e40ff1302a42783dcc01892afbd/proposals/0274-quick-look-impredicativity.rst#the-typing-rule-for-